# Applying geometric sum formula in context with indicator function

Tags: geometric-series

Consider the following:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} v^k \mathbb{1}_{ \{K \geq k\}} \overset{!}{=} \frac{1-v^n}{1-v} 
$$

$K=0,1,2,3,.......$ is a random variable. I do not think that I can apply the geometric sum formula here. I do not know how many summands will be on the left side?

What do you think?

Comment: In this case you could just write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\min\{n-1,K\}} v^k.
$$

Comment: So I could write: $...= \frac{1-v^{min \{ K+1,n \} }}{1-v}$ ?

Comment: Something like that, yes. Keep in mind that this quantity is a random variable since it is a function of $K$.

Comment: Thank you Math1000:)